# R read csv but not got the real result

Tags: r, csv

I try to read csv file but the outcome not exactly same with the data source. Say like date field contains 05/01/15, I got 5/1/2015.
How to deal with this so whatever I got is same with the data source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the read.table (or other `read.[...]`) with the colClasses arguments and indicate you want this column read as character. See `?read.table` for more details.

From this helpfile:

> Note: to suppress all conversions including those of numeric columns,
>   set colClasses = "character".